# How to get facebook friends birthdays using Hackbook sample in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get Facebook friends birthdays using Hackbook sample app in Android,
Getting Name and Image only.....

Comment: @LawrenceChoy actually i am new in Fb Development so i have no idea what to use?? please give me some guidance....as you like

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: (using FQL. I have never tested a Graph API equivalent and not sure if it is possible either)

```
String queryBirthdays = "SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND birthday_date >= '01/03' AND birthday_date <= '06/03' ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
Bundle bunEvents = new Bundle();
bunEvents.putString("method", "fql.query");
bunEvents.putString("query", queryBirthdays);
String responseEventsQuery = Utility.mFacebook.request(bunEvents);
```

Then parse the `responseEventsQuery`. For example, like this:

```
JSONArray JAEvents = new JSONArray(responseEventsQuery);

for (int i = 0; i < JAEvents.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject JOEvents = JAEvents.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

**Note:** You will probably have to play around with these parameters: `01/03` and `06/03` in the query to get the necessary result. Try the query in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) (In the FQL Query tab)